# Hashing an Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, hash

I have currently been trying to hash an image from my browser using javascript.  However, I've been hashing a string of the dataURL or the pixel data that I've been retrieving from the canvas element in HTML.  This is obviously not the same as hashing the raw data of the image which is what I would like to do.

For example the data that would be used for the same image in the php hash file function.

Does anybody know how I can access this raw image data using javascript to get a hash value that would be equivalent to the result hash I get from PHP hash_file($file)?

Thanks!

Comment: How is "raw data of the image" not the "pixel data"? Of course, image data is no file.

Comment: The raw data I'm looking for is 0 and 1's where as the pixel data is a string of numbers consisting of numbers from 0-255 (if I'm not mistaken on the range).  I'm suspecting the function in PHP is working with the 0 and 1's, not the 0-255 values concatenated together.

Comment: What do you mean "string of numbers"? Do you have a string containing binary data or an array of bytes?

Comment: 0-255 is only 8 times 0s and 1s.

Comment: Right, is that to say that what the binary data representing the image is also made of?  I was under the impression the bytes of the file/image weren't exactly in relation with the pixels.  Otherwise characters could also be representations of pixels and I guess I just hadn't seen that.

Comment: The binary data of an image doesn't correspond to the pixel data. PNGs, JPGs, and other images use compression. There's also other information stored inside the images data.

Comment: String of data meaning at the current moment I've been alternating between either traversing through an array of pixel values(numbers) and concatenating them into a string.  And in the other case, a string of data being the data URL of the image which is just a string with varying characters, not necessarily numbers in that case, sorry.

Comment: MattDiamant, thanks.  That answers the first question in the comments much better than I could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the raw data of an image with an XHR request to that image file location.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/my/image/file.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; // this will accept the response as an ArrayBuffer
xhr.onload = function(buffer) {
    var words = new Uint32Array(buffer),
        hex = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      hex += words.get(i).toString(16);  // this will convert it to a 4byte hex string
    }
    console.log(hex);
};
xhr.send();
```

After that, you can use whatever hashing algorithm you'd like. Here's a library of them: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Comment: Ah, this response serves the purpose but for security purposes I'm hoping to have everything done client side, independent of any server and working only with the image element in browser.

Comment: You're already grabbing the image file from a server, right? This is just grabbing it again. Where are you loading the image from that you can't load it again? Otherwise, what's wrong with the canvas+dataURL solution that you've probably come across?

Comment: I am, the problem with this is just added security.  For example if I'm looking to digitally sign this image, the byte data I'm relying on the server to correctly send back to me is susceptible to alterations( assuming http, no ssl).  I'd like to be signing the image that I see, to be truly signing what I see.

EDIT:  However, if this can also reload the image in browser according to the data I receive, then that would actually work.

Comment: The problem with dataURL is that cross browser, the dataURL's are inconsistent.

Comment: Well after my last comment, I realize now your solution will probably be the only correct one...  guess I'll have to work around the small security drawback.